# Lua | Как установить противоположное значение переменной?

Tags: lua

Есть код

```
function check()
if isPlayer then
--установить противоположное значение
Пробовал isPlayer ~= isPlayer 
end
```

Но не вышло

Comment: `isPlayer = not isPlayer`?

Comment: К вышенаписанному добавлю, что то что вы "пробовали" - не имеет вообще никакого смысла, так переменная всегда будет равна себе.